# Which of the foll. powershell script is correct way to install a timer job into SharePoint?

Tags: powershell, solution-package, timer-jobs

1:  `install-spsolution Solution.wsp -webapplication "webapplication" -GACDeployment –force`

2:  `install-spsolution Solution.wsp -GACDeployment –force`

Which of above is best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only deploy a package using -WebApplication if the artifacts in the solution has WebApplication scope. When packaging the solution package Visual Studio will handle this for you detecting the scope of the artifacts.

You will get an error in PowerShell if you try to deploy a solution that has WebApplication scoped artifacts at farm scope and vice versa.

To check if a solution has one scope or another do this

`Get-SPSolution <yoursolution.wsp> | Select ContainsWebApplicationResource`

Comment: I have 4 project solutions scoped at Farm, WebApplication, Site and Web level respectively...  Can you tell me the powershell to be used. Do you mean to say that on the the project with scope as WebApplication must be installed using -WebApplication and this must be omitted from other solutions?

Comment: Yep that is correct. Solutions can only have Farm and WebApplication scope. Features can have Farm, WebApplication, Site and Web scope

Comment: Normally timer job based solutions (provided they don't have Web Parts) are candidate for globally deployed solutions.

Answer (score 1):

```
SPSolution.ContainsWebApplicationResource can be used to check whether solution contains web application resources or not. In PowerShell scripts, you can use following commands:

# Deploy solution
$Solution = Get-SPSolution | ? {($_.Name -eq $SolutionPackageName) -and ($_.Deployed -eq $false)}
if($Solution -ne $null)
{
    if($Solution.ContainsWebApplicationResource)   
    {
        Install-SPSolution -Identity $SolutionPackageName -WebApplication $WebApplication -GACDeployment -Confirm:$false
    }
    else
    {
        Install-SPSolution -Identity $SolutionPackageName -GACDeployment -Confirm:$false
    }  
}
```